# I am facing the issue while uploading the file to server using spring mvc and retrofit 2.0

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload, retrofit2

This is my backend method.

```
  @IsAdmin
@RequestMapping(value = "/student/upload/file/{operation}/{format}/", 
method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ResponseEntity<?> handleStudentFile(@PathVariable String 
operation, @PathVariable String format, @RequestParam("file") 
  MultipartFile file) {
    return studentHandler.handleStudent(operation, format, file);
}
```

And following is my android method,

```
@Multipart
    @POST("admin/student/upload/file/{operation}/{format}/")
    Call<ServerResponse> uploadNew(@Path("operation") String 
 operation, @Path("format") String format, @PartMap Map<String, 
MultipartBody> map);
```

and

```
   Map<String, MultipartBody> map = new HashMap<>();
           File file = new File(filePath);
        MultipartBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("file", file.getName(),

RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/vnd.ms-excel"), file))
//                    .addFormDataPart("some-field", "some-value")
                    .build();
            map.put("file\"; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"", 
requestBody);
            ApiCallService.action(getActivity(), map, 
ACTION_UPLOAD_EXCEL);
```

With the above method file is not going with proper contents,

I have tried this way,

```
  @Multipart
    @POST("admin/student/upload/file/{operation}/{format}/")
    public Call<ServerResponse> upload(@Path("operation") String 
operation, @Path("format") String format, @Part("file") RequestBody 
file);



 MultipartBody.Builder multiPartBody =new 
 MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart("file", file.getName(),

 RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/vnd.ms-excel"), 
 file));

             ApiCallService.action(getActivity(), 
  multiPartBody.build(), ACTION_UPLOAD_EXCEL2);
```

Help me guyz what am i doing wrong, I am stuck.

I am getting and exception in backend,

```
 org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Your 
  InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream
```